# How many people have to be gathered to ensure at least 9 people have the same first letter of their first name?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I know I use generalized pigeon hole principle where $n/k= m$. I know $n$ is pigeons and $k$ is pigeonholes. I know I have to do n/#=m for this one. So its n/#=9. Im not sure what would be pigeonholes in this case.

Comment: Hint: How many people can you have without this happening?

Comment: I think the number of letters in the alphabet should play a role.

Comment: So the number of letters in the alphabet (26) would be my k?

Comment: How many does it take to be sure that two have the same first letter?  How many letters are there?  How many does it take for three to have the same first letter?

Comment: To ross, for two to have the same letter i think there needs to be 52 people? im using what my ta gave me as n/k=m, so n/26=2

Comment: Put 8 pigeons in each pigeon hole, then add a pigeon.

Comment: No, you need $27$ to get two people sharing a letter.  The first $26$ can all be different, but when you add a $27th$ there must be one sharing.  Similarly, you can have $52$ people with two having each letter, but the $53rd$ must make there be one letter with three people.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the number is $26\times 8 +1=209$.

Answer (score 0):

## 34

26 people can have different first letters of their names. The 27th person has to share, then you have 2 people sharing the first letter. If a new person (the 28th) is added with a different letter than the already shared ones, then 2 more people share a letter, but if the new person has the same first letter as the other two who are already sharing then only  1 more person shares a letter. So in order to ensure that 9 share, then 27 (with 2 sharing) plus 7 more is 34 with 9 sharing.

Adjust this if there is a different alphabet with something other than 26 starting letters

Comment: I think the intent of the question was that all 9 people should have the same first letter, not that each of them should share a first letter with someone not necessarily among the 9.

Comment: Can we get clarification, the question is unclear about this